# How can a button in an iframe open a new url in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension which adds a bar at the top of a webpage. i have inserted the iframe in the content script using

```
document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);
```

The iframe has a button

```
<button id="mybutton">Click to help</button>
```

When the user clicks the button I want to redirect them to a new url in the same window. Is this possible?

The reason I want to do this is on certain websites I would like to change the url to include an additional parameter. I chose the iframe option as it more visible than an extension in the bar. Therefore if there is an alternative way to do this I would be happy to learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iframe.....

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeParent(e){
parent.location="http://google.com.au";
}
function onLoad(){

document.querySelector("#mybutton").onclick = changeParent;

}
</script>
<body onload="onLoad()">

<a id="mybutton">Change Parents URL</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Would be a good case for info bars if they ever come out of experimental....
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.infobars.html